# Spacing Question on the * operator for XAML with Grids

Tags: wpf, xaml

So, I just wanted to understand why this was happening in my WPF app as it seems to be adding a "space" or faint line without me wanting it...

I have the following XAML

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ShowGridLines="False" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>          
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"  CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Height="10" Background="Black"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"  Background="Black">

    </Border>           
    <Border Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" Height="10" Background="Black"/>
</Grid>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Button>Some Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Which renders the following window...

[image: Window Pic]

The problem is if you look closely at the last row connector you will see a faint gray line...

[image: Faint Gray Line Pic]

If however I replace the `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` on the inner grid with a fix pixel size (i.e. `<RowDefinition Height="300"/>`) the line goes away. Why exactly when I am using the * value does it seem to be adding this "grey line" / "space"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is Anti-Aliasing

1. Your effect
2. SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
3. UseLayoutRounding="False"
4. RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like layout rounding problem to me. If you are using WPF 4, try setting `UseLayoutRounding="true"` on your outer grid. Else, take a look at `SnapToDevicePixels`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.uselayoutrounding.aspx

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, both answers worked, I upvoted you for the feedback!